# Add filter on executable files in filechooser dialog using pygtk when OS is Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am using pygtk to create a file chooser widget. I am using Ubuntu OS. I want to put a filter in selecting files. My chooser widget should only select executable files (diamond icons or in Ubuntu). I am trying to use below code:

```
dialog  = gtk.FileChooserDialog(title=None,action=gtk.FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN,
                                  buttons=(gtk.STOCK_CANCEL,gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL,gtk.STOCK_OK,gtk.RESPONSE_OK))

filter_file = gtk.FileFilter()
filter_file.add_pattern("*.bin")
filter_file.add_pattern("*.run")
filter_file.add_pattern("*.sh")
dialog.add_filter(filter_images)
dialog.show()
```

It is not working. It does not show the executable files in chooser window. Is there any way we can put filter on executable files because it seems like Ubuntu does not have any extension for executable files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with gtk, but a quick look at the [docs](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkfilefilter.html#method-gtkfilefilter--add-custom) for `gtk.FileFilter` leads me to believe that using `FileFilter.add_custom` instead of `FileFilter.add_pattern` will allow you to write a custom filter function that can get the permission bits for the file to determine if it is executable or not.  For example:

```
import os

def executable_filter(filter_info, data):
    path = filter_info[0]
#   Note that this only checks if the current effective user may execute the file.  If you need to know if owner/group/other can execute it, you'll probably want something from the os.stat module.
    return os.access(path, os.X_OK)

filter_file.add_custom((gtk.FILE_FILTER_FILENAME, None, None, None), executable_filter, None)
```

I can't test this, because I don't have gtk set up, but I think this approach will work.

Comment: It worked. I just changed (gtk.FILE_FILTER_FILENAME, None, None, None) in argument by gtk.FILE_FILTER_FILENAME to remove the error. thanks :)